# Multivariable asymptotic regression model

Tags: regression, asymptotics

Is there a way to extend following univariable asymptotic regression model to include additional variables?

$$
Y = Asym + (R0 - Asym)* e^{(-lrc * T)}
$$
$Asym$ = maximum attainable value of $Y$ 
$R0$ = initial value at time 0 (Intercept) 
$lrc$ = rate of $Y$ increase while $T$ increases

How would I extend this model if I would like to add an additional variable $X$ to the model?

Example: 
I have a concentration $Y$, which follows an asymptotic growth over time $T$. 
Now I would like to assess the association between $Y$ and another concentration $X$, while conditioning/adjusting for the asymptotic growth over time $T$ ($T$ is likely to be a confounder of $Y$ and $X$).

How would I do this?